# Cocoa-Touch - How parse local Json file

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, cocoa-touch

I'm newbie in iOS dev and I'm trying to parse a local Json file such as

`{"quizz":[{"id":"1","Q1":"When Mickey was born","R1":"1920","R2":"1965","R3":"1923","R4","1234","response","1920"},{"id":"1","Q1":"When start the cold war","R1":"1920","R2":"1965","R3":"1923","rep4","1234","reponse","1920"}]}`

here is my code:

```
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json"];
NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
// Parse the string into JSON
NSDictionary *json = [myJSON JSONValue];

// Get all object
NSArray *items = [json valueForKeyPath:@"quizz"];

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [items objectEnumerator];
NSDictionary* item;
while (item = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject]) {
    NSLog(@"clientId = %@",  [item objectForKey:@"id"]);
    NSLog(@"clientName = %@",[item objectForKey:@"Q1"]);
    NSLog(@"job = %@",       [item objectForKey:@"Q2"]);
}
```

I found on this site a sample but I get the following error

-JSONValue failed. Error is: Token 'value separator' not expected after object key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JSON has a strict key/Value notation, your key/value pairs for R4 and response are not correct. Try this:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"quizz\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"Q1\":\"When Mickey was born\",\"R1\":\"1920\",\"R2\":\"1965\",\"R3\":\"1923\",\"R4\":\"1234\",\"response\":\"1920\"}]}";
```

<sup>If you read the string from a file, you don't need all the slashes</sup>
Your file would be something like this:

> {"quizz":[{"id":"1","Q1":"When Mickey was
>   born","R1":"1920","R2":"1965","R3":"1923","R4":"1234","response":"1920"},{"id":"1","Q1":"When
>   start the cold
>   war","R1":"1920","R2":"1965","R3":"1923","R4":"1234","reponse":"1920"}]}

---

I tested with this code:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"quizz\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"Q1\":\"When Mickey was born\",\"R1\":\"1920\",\"R2\":\"1965\",\"R3\":\"1923\",\"R4\":\"1234\",\"response\":\"1920\"}, {\"id\":\"1\",\"Q1\":\"When start the cold war\",\"R1\":\"1920\",\"R2\":\"1965\",\"R3\":\"1923\",\"R4\":\"1234\",\"reponse\":\"1920\"}]}";
NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
NSError *error =  nil;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray *items = [json valueForKeyPath:@"quizz"];

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [items objectEnumerator];
NSDictionary* item;
while (item = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject]) {
    NSLog(@"clientId = %@",  [item objectForKey:@"id"]);
    NSLog(@"clientName = %@",[item objectForKey:@"Q1"]);
    NSLog(@"job = %@",       [item objectForKey:@"Q2"]);
}
```

I got the impression, that you copied old code, as you are not using apple's serialization and a Enumerator instead of [Fast Enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html). The whole enumeration stuff could be written simple as

```
NSArray *items = [json valueForKeyPath:@"quizz"];
for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
    NSLog(@"clientId = %@",  [item objectForKey:@"id"]);
    NSLog(@"clientName = %@",[item objectForKey:@"Q1"]);
    NSLog(@"job = %@",       [item objectForKey:@"Q2"]);
}
```

or even fancier with [block based enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW5), hwere you have additionaly an index if needed to the fast and secure enumeration.

```
NSArray *items = [json valueForKeyPath:@"quizz"];
[items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *item , NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"clientId = %@",  [item objectForKey:@"id"]);
    NSLog(@"clientName = %@",[item objectForKey:@"Q1"]);
    NSLog(@"job = %@",       [item objectForKey:@"Q2"]);
}];
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. One other question, how I can  retrieve a specific object index in the array and browse the key value? I mean if I want to select the second object directly and display the id value?

Comment: once you parsed the json string, you will have nsarrays and dictionaries. so for array you can do `item = [items objectAtIndex:1]` to get the second item. But this has nothing to do with json anymore. this is standard array/dictionary stuff.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"json"];
NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSError *error =  nil;
NSArray *jsonDataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to find errors in your JSON string.
In this case, it says you have non-valid JSON near `"R4"`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo in your json file.

Replace
`"R4","1234","response","1920"` with `"R4":"1234","response":"1920"`
and
`"rep4","1234","reponse","1920"` with `"rep4":"1234","response":"1920"`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.3**
I use a utility method to convert JSON files to a Dictionary:

```
func getDictionaryFromJSON(jsonFileName: String) -> [String: AnyObject]? {
    guard let filepath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(jsonFileName, ofType: "json") else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filepath) else {
        return nil
    }

    do {
        let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
        return dict
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```